# PostgreSQL, get all partitioned table names and all NOT partiotioned table names

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.6

How can I get the name of all the non partitioned tables in my DB ? I use PostgresSQL 9.6

And how do I get the names of the partitioned tables only ?

For now I have the names of the partions in my DB, specifying a table name, but I need to do that dinamically.

```
SELECT i.inhrelid::regclass AS child
FROM   pg_inherits i
WHERE  i.inhparent = 'public.documento'::regclass;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Updated**

for partitionned tables:

```
select distinct inhparent::regclass from pg_inherits
```

and not partitions smthlike:

```
select oid::regclass::text relation
from pg_class where relkind = 'r'
except
select distinct inhparent::regclass::text
from pg_inherits
except
select distinct inhrelid::regclass::text
from pg_inherits
;
```

note: to filter results, just use `where`, like

```
with l as (
<code above>
)
select * from l where relation not like 'pg_%';
```

Comment: for the second one it says "sql_features" relation it doesn't exists. The first works perfectly

Comment: can you provide me an example ? I don't know much of this thing.

Comment: @Fjordo try this (in that second query): `select concat(schemaname, '.', tablename)::regclass
from pg_tables`. Remove cast to `regclass` if you get permission denied error.

Comment: I tryed, and I did not receive any error, But there are too many tables in the returned list. There are also the pg_* ones, which i don't want. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @ŁukaszKamiński thank you for your comments! Fjordo - updated the answer to both avoid permission problems and limit the list

Comment: @Fjordo did I answer your question?

Comment: I also needed to add and tablename not like 'sql_%';, to your code, to filter others unwanted tables.

Comment: Just a small note for casting regclass to text, you might end up with double quoted text value, but from pg_tables you never get those double quotes - unless you do `quote_ident(tablename)::text`.

Comment: @ŁukaszKamiński thank you again. chaged to pg_class with relkind='r' instead

Answer (score 4):

`pg_inherits` records information about table and index inheritance hierarchies.
If you need to get all partitioned tables only(exclude partitioned indexes), we can use:

```sql
select relnamespace::regnamespace::text schema_name, oid::regclass::text table_name from pg_class
where relkind = 'p' and oid in (select distinct inhparent from pg_inherits)
order by schema_name, table_name;
```